# Getting index of item while processing a list using map in python

Tags: python

While processing a list using map(), I want to access index of the item while inside lambda. How can I do that?

For example

```
ranked_users = ['jon','bob','jane','alice','chris']
user_details = map(lambda x: {'name':x, 'rank':?}, ranked_users)
```

How can I get rank of each user in above example?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
In [3]: user_details = [{'name':x, 'rank':i} for i,x in enumerate(ranked_users)] 

In [4]: user_details
Out[4]: 
[{'name': 'jon', 'rank': 0},
 {'name': 'bob', 'rank': 1},
 {'name': 'jane', 'rank': 2},
 {'name': 'alice', 'rank': 3},
 {'name': 'chris', 'rank': 4}]
```

---

PS. My first answer was

```
user_details = map(lambda (i,x): {'name':x, 'rank':i}, enumerate(ranked_users))
```

I'd strongly recommend using a list comprehension or generator expression over `map` and `lambda` whenever possible. List comprehensions are more readable, and tend to be faster to boot.

Comment: Shouldn't lambda's parameters be without parentheses?

Comment: @dheerosaur Not in this case since the next() operation on enumerate returns a tuple. This lambda is equivalent to def foo((i,x))

Comment: @dheerosaur: Actually, the parentheses are mandatory. `enumerate` generates tuples (a single object).

Comment: @Rod, @unutbu: Got it. So, `lambda`s can't unpack tuples as list comprehensions do.

Comment: @dheerosaur: Yes, lambdas do unpack differently than list comprehensions (in Python2). Note that in Python3, lambdas refuse to unpack at all: See http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#tuple_params.

Comment: If you don't pass a `lamdba` in, but instead use a `def something(index, character)`, this doesn't appear to work. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you could use a [list comprehension](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/mapping_lists.html) rather than map() and lambda.

```
ranked_users = ['jon','bob','jane','alice','chris']
user_details = [{'name' : x, 'rank' : ranked_users.index(x)} for x in ranked_users]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'jon', 'rank': 0}, {'name': 'bob', 'rank': 1}, {'name': 'jane', 'rank': 2}, {'name': 'alice', 'rank': 3}, {'name': 'chris', 'rank': 4}]
```

List comprehensions are very powerful and are also [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map/1247490#1247490) than a combination of `map` and `lambda`.

Comment: `list.index()` is only appropriate if all members of `ranked_users` are unique. Given `ranked_users = ['chris','chris']` `user_details` outputs `[{'name': 'chris', 'rank': 0}, {'name': 'chris', 'rank': 0}]` where it should be `[{'name': 'chris', 'rank': 0}, {'name': 'chris', 'rank': 1}]`.

Comment: It would only make sense (given this data) for the members to be unique though…

Comment: Sure. Your answer fits the example. I just thought it would be a good idea to state the uniqueness caveat for anyone who comes across this post.

Comment: using index function call on ranked_users list is overengineered little bit. Python for expression iterates over objects in datastructure

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the question was about map function and preferred answer is partly correct due to syntax error caused by putting tuple argument to lambda `lambda (i,x)`

idea of enumerate is nice and proper solution would be:

```
map(lambda x: {'name':x[1], 'rank':x[0]}, enumerate(ranked_users))
```

and some timing to compare speed with comprehension:

```
def with_map():
    ranked_users = range(10 ** 6)
    list(map(lambda x: {'name': x[1], 'rank': x[0]}, enumerate(ranked_users)))

def by_comprehension():
    ranked_users = range(10 ** 6)
    [{'name': x, 'rank': i} for i, x in enumerate(ranked_users)]

from timeit import timeit
time_with_map = timeit(with_map, number=10)
time_with_comprehension = timeit(by_comprehension, number=10)

print('list comprehension is about %.2f x faster than map in this test case' % (time_with_map/time_with_comprehension))
```

test result: list comprehension is about 1.31 x faster than map in this test case

Answer (score 6):

Actually here is a more elegant, verbose solution than using an enumerate tuple in the map (because of tuple indexing). Map can take more iterables as arguments so let's use it.

```
map(lambda user, user_id: (user_id, user), ranked_users, range(ranked_users.__len__()))
```