# Map operation Last Element exception

Tags: python, list

```
#Right now
list(map(lambda x: f1.write(x + ','),feature))
# Would like it to be:
list(map(lambda x: if(x = map.end) f1.write(x) else: f1.write(x),feature))
```

Like the sample code above is there any thing I can do to exclude or make an exception such that the last element of the map does something else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting index of item while processing a list using map in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432762/getting-index-of-item-while-processing-a-list-using-map-in-python)

Comment: Use enumerate to keep tack of the current index and compare with the len inside the lambda expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use map only on `feature[:-1]` which are all the elements of feature except the last one.
and then write the last element :

Edit : because feature is a map object, we convert it to a list before

```
feature = list(feature)
res = list(map(lambda x: f1.write(x + ','),feature[:-1]))
res.append(f1.write(feature[-1]))
```

Comment: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable. I dont think you can access maps like that, feature[:-1]

Comment: What is the type of 'feature' ?

Comment: The type of feature is a map

Comment: OK, I didn't know that ! I edited my post, you can first convert it to a list.